# SQL syntax error: unknown column

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to run this query:

```
$result = db_query("INSERT INTO `timesheets` (clientid, candid, weekending, department, orderno, basicpay, basiccharge, otpay, otcharge, ot2pay, ot2charge, status, hue, huc) VALUES (`$client`, `$cand`, `$week_ending`, `$department`, `$order_no`, `$basic_pay`, `$basic_charge`, `$ot_pay`, `$ot_charge`, `$ot2_pay`, `$ot2_charge`, `$status`, `$hue`, `$huc`)");
    if($result){
        print 'Success! ID of last inserted record is';
    } 
    else {
        die('Error : ' . db_error());
    }
```

These are the values from the form

```
    $client = db_quote($_POST['client']);
    $cand = db_quote($_POST['cand']);
    $order_no = db_quote($_POST['order_no']);
    $department = db_quote($_POST['department']);
    $week_ending = db_quote($_POST['week_ending']);
    $basic_pay = db_quote($_POST['basic_pay']);
    $hue = db_quote($_POST['hue']);
    $basic_charge = db_quote($_POST['basic_charge']);
    $huc = db_quote($_POST['huc']);
    $ot_pay = db_quote($_POST['ot1_pay']);
    $ot_charge = db_quote($_POST['ot1_charge']);
    $ot2_pay = db_quote($_POST['ot2_pay']);
    $ot2_charge = db_quote($_POST['ot2_charge']);   
    $status = 'cand';
```

The value of `$client` in this instance is "725". The error I am getting is Error : Unknown column ''725'' in 'field list'.

How can this be - the column name in the timesheets table is `clientid`. I'm trying to put the value 725 into the `clientid` column. Is there a syntax error somewhere? The error message doesn't seem to make sense?

Comment: Can you print the query just before execute the statement??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When setting the values in MySQL you can't use the backtick character to denote a field, you'll need to use either `'` or `"` to enclose your variables.

Use of a back-tick is for naming a field.  It's a quirk of MySQL.

Your query line should be:

```
$result = db_query("INSERT INTO `timesheets` (clientid, candid, weekending, department, orderno, basicpay, basiccharge, otpay, otcharge, ot2pay, ot2charge, status, hue, huc) VALUES ('$client', '$cand', '$week_ending', '$department', '$order_no', '$basic_pay', '$basic_charge', '$ot_pay', '$ot_charge', '$ot2_pay', '$ot2_charge', '$status', '$hue', '$huc')");
```

Comment: I'm using this which works VALUES ($client, $cand, $week_ending, $department, $order_no, $basic_pay, $basic_charge, $ot_pay, $ot_charge, $ot2_pay, $ot2_charge, '$status', $hue, $huc)
The column types are all varchar of varying lengths. Why then can I leave $department without quotes but doing so with $status gives an error? Isn't $department a string also?

Answer (score 1):

The correct query would be like below one:

```
"INSERT INTO 'timesheets' (clientid, candid, weekending, department, orderno, basicpay, basiccharge, otpay, otcharge, ot2pay, ot2charge, status, hue, huc) 
VALUES ('$client', '$cand', '$week_ending', '$department', '$order_no', '$basic_pay', '$basic_charge', '$ot_pay', '$ot_charge', '$ot2_pay', '$ot2_charge', '$status', '$hue', '$huc')
```

Comment: That would give a syntax error as the variable `$status` is a string, and would need to be treated as such in the values section of the statement

Comment: @gabe3886 I'm now getting that error! Error : Unknown column 'cand' in 'field list'. Using '$status' fixed it

Comment: Have you declared 'cand' ?

Comment: I've declared `$status = "cand";`. So in VALUES I need to wrap strings in quotes like so `'$status'`. Why does it work for the rest without the quotes? Isn't `$department` a string also?

Comment: Yeah, You need to wrap the strings with quotes if column type is of varchar in table.

Comment: I'm using this which works `VALUES ($client, $cand, $week_ending, $department, $order_no, $basic_pay, $basic_charge, $ot_pay, $ot_charge, $ot2_pay, $ot2_charge, '$status', $hue, $huc)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83957/discussion-between-code-monk-and-ian-butler).

Comment: @IanButler The department is most likely a string, but the call to `db_quote` is potentially correctly wrapping the strings ahead of their usage

Comment: @gabe3886 Well spotted! Yes "cand" isn't being passed into `db_quote()`. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
$result = db_query("INSERT INTO `timesheets` (clientid, candid, weekending, department, orderno, basicpay, basiccharge, otpay, otcharge, ot2pay, ot2charge, status, hue, huc) VALUES ('".$client."', '".$cand."', '".$week_ending."', '".$department."', '".$order_no."', '".$basic_pay."', '".$basic_charge."', '".$ot_pay."', '".$ot_charge."', '".$ot2_pay."', '".$ot2_charge."', '".$status."', '".$hue."', '".$huc."')");
```

Comment: Because the values aren't quoted in this SQL, any strings will cause an error

Answer (score 0):

Please pay attention to the quotation marks during the creation of the query.

The **INSERT** statement should something like that:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (col_name_1, col_name_2, col_name_3) VALUES('$param_1', '$param_2', '$param_3')
```

Note that the `table_name` is written without quotation marks, while each value is delimited by a single quotes.

You can find the official documentation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html) and a full example [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-insert-query.htm).

By the way, the query for your code should be something like that:

```
 $sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO timesheets (clientid, candid, weekending, department, orderno,basicpay, basiccharge, otpay, otcharge, ot2pay, ot2charge, status, hue, huc) VALUES ('$client', '$cand', '$week_ending', '$department', '$order_no', '$basic_pay', '$basic_charge', '$ot_pay', '$ot_charge', '$ot2_pay', '$ot2_charge', '$status', '$hue', '$huc')";
```

Comment: In the question, the table_name part isn't in quotations, it's in back ticks with is completely valid and in some places encouraged